# Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component. in TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

I got this error

**Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.**

How to fix this ?

When I remove touchable opacity, it's not showing anymore

```js
                  <View style={styles.SaD}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) = props.locationSetState(1)}> // here
                                <Text style={styles.text1}>Choose your starting point</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) = props.locationSetState(2)}>
                                <Text style={styles.text1}>Choose destination</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

details are not sufficient to understand your problem but according to what I understand from your code try using react hooks  and try this

```
function App() {

  const [state,setState]=React.useState(null);
  console.log(state);
  return (
                       <View style={styles.SaD}>
                            
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => setState(1)}>
                                <Text style={styles.text1}>Choose destination</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => setState(2)}>
                                <Text style={styles.text1}>Choose destination</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
  );
}
```